# markmap: Insert the mindmap to the HTML

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, hugo, mindmap

I wanted to use a mindmap on [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/), and [markmap](https://github.com/gera2ld/markmap) was exactly what I wanted. But I'm very unfamiliar with its syntax. (see below code-block) I don't even know what language it is (is it [typescript-arrow-function](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/arrow-function)?)

```js
((e,t)=>{
    const{Markmap:r}=e();
    window.mm=r.create("svg#mindmap-other",null,t)
})(
    ()=>window.markmap,  /* parameter e */
    {}  /* parameter t */
);
```

I hope I can integrate the bottom two scripts into one; these two are very similar. Please help me or tell me where to find the grammar document, thanks!

You can try it by yourself on this [site](https://markmap.js.org/repl/)

and I provide my version as below.

my question is: **How can I merge the last two scripts into one** to make the code beautiful?)

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Markmap</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markmap-view@0.2.0"></script>
  <style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mindmap {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<svg id="mindmap-lang" class="mindmap"></svg>
<svg id="mindmap-other" class="mindmap"></svg>
</body>

<script>
/* script-Lang */
((e,t)=>{
const{Markmap:r}=e();
window.mm=r.create("svg#mindmap-lang",null,t)
})(
()=>window.markmap,{
"t":"root","d":0,"v":"Lang","c":
[
  {"t":"heading","d":1,"v":"Lang", "c":[
      {"t":"heading","d":2,"v":"<a href=\"https://www.python.org/\">Python</a>"},
      {"t":"heading","d":2,"v":"JS", "c":[
          {"t": "heading", "d":3, "v":"jquery"},
          {"t": "heading", "d":3, "v":"d3js"}
        ]
      }
    ]},
  {"t":"heading","d":1,"v":"News", "c":[]}
]}
);

</script>

<script>
/* script-Other */
((e,t)=>{
const{Markmap:r}=e();
window.mm=r.create("svg#mindmap-other",null,t)
})(
()=>window.markmap,{
  "t":"heading","d":0,"v":"Other", "c":
  [
    {"t":"heading","d":1,"v":"H1"},
    {"t":"heading","d":1,"v":"H1", "c":[
        {"t": "heading", "d":2, "v":"H2"},
        {"t": "heading", "d":2, "v":"H2"}
      ]
    }
  ]}
);

</script>
```

It's wonderful if you can explain what is going on below:

```js
((e,t)=>{
    const{Markmap:r}=e();
    window.mm=r.create("svg",null,t)
})(
    ()=>window.markmap,  /* parameter e */
    {}  /* parameter t */
);
```

---

above code have two scripts `script-Lang` and `script-Other`

in order to avoid confusion, I decided to post the results image below
[image]

---

Here's what I did on my Hugo site. I provided it under below, for someone who wants it.

[Here](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/gohugo-theme-ananke/blob/007d6a44c5baf80ad23ac6bd6c31deaf4718d6f7/layouts/custom_layout/site/navigation/site-markmap.html) is  I am trying to embed the markmap to Hugo so far. ([demo](https://carsonslovoka.github.io/old-home/site-markmap/))

I want to add another SVG(mind-map) of the date site under the section, so I will need multiple SVG on the same page, which is why I need to integrate the above code together.

Comment: Hey the script that you have given looks like an IIFE for arrow function. and yes you guessed it right ! Its type script. I removed the second script tag and it seems to work well what is the use of it ?

Comment: @XxSTREKxX I update the question, and the second script is to create ``script-Other``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Those function inside the script tag is know as [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) it runs as soon as it is defined...

It takes in two parameter they are `window.markmap` and another is the `object` to be represented.

so you can combine them by making a same IIFE like i've done..

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Markmap</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markmap-view@0.2.0"></script>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .mindmap {
      display: block;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="mindmap-lang" class="mindmap"></svg>
  <svg id="mindmap-other" class="mindmap"></svg>
</body>

<script>
  /* script-Lang */
  ((e) => {
    const {
      Markmap: r
    } = e();
    window.mm = r.create("svg#mindmap-lang", null, {
      "t": "root",
      "d": 0,
      "v": "Lang",
      "c": [{
          "t": "heading",
          "d": 1,
          "v": "Lang",
          "c": [{
              "t": "heading",
              "d": 2,
              "v": "<a href=\"https://www.python.org/\">Python</a>"
            },
            {
              "t": "heading",
              "d": 2,
              "v": "JS",
              "c": [{
                  "t": "heading",
                  "d": 3,
                  "v": "jquery"
                },
                {
                  "t": "heading",
                  "d": 3,
                  "v": "d3js"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "t": "heading",
          "d": 1,
          "v": "News",
          "c": []
        }
      ]
    })
    window.mm - r.create("svg#mindmap-other", null, {
      "t": "heading",
      "d": 0,
      "v": "Other",
      "c": [{
          "t": "heading",
          "d": 1,
          "v": "H1"
        },
        {
          "t": "heading",
          "d": 1,
          "v": "H1",
          "c": [{
              "t": "heading",
              "d": 2,
              "v": "H2"
            },
            {
              "t": "heading",
              "d": 2,
              "v": "H2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
  })(() => window.markmap);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@XxSTREKxX has explained very clearly that I organize the answer into a style that I prefer.

The key points are as follows,

```js
(
  (para1, para2, ... ,para_n)=>{
    /* implement your logical */  
  }
)(input_para1, input_para2, ...,input_para_n)
```

Full code of my example,

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Markmap</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markmap-view@0.2.0"></script>
  <style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .mindmap {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }  
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<svg id="mindmap-lang" class="mindmap"></svg>
<svg id="mindmap-other" class="mindmap"></svg>
</body>

<script>
((e, lang_json, other_json)=>{
    const{Markmap:r}=e();
    window.mm=r.create("svg#mindmap-lang",null,lang_json)
    window.mm=r.create("svg#mindmap-other",null,other_json)
})(
  ()=>window.markmap, /* parameter e */
  {  /* parameter lang_json */
    "t":"root","d":0,"v":"Lang","c":
    [
      {"t":"heading","d":1,"v":"Lang", "c":[
        {"t":"heading","d":2,"v":"<a href=\"https://www.python.org/\">Python</a>"},
        {"t":"heading","d":2,"v":"JS", "c":[
          {"t": "heading", "d":3, "v":"jquery"},
          {"t": "heading", "d":3, "v":"d3js"}
        ]
        }
      ]},
      {"t":"heading","d":1,"v":"News", "c":[]}
    ]
  },
  {  /* parameter other_json */
    "t":"heading","d":0,"v":"Other", "c":
    [
      {"t":"heading","d":1,"v":"H1"},
      {"t":"heading","d":1,"v":"H1", "c":[
          {"t": "heading", "d":2, "v":"H2"},
          {"t": "heading", "d":2, "v":"H2"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
);
</script>
```