# Looking for an example for using markmap in HTML file with Markdown

Tags: javascript, mindmap

I want to use [markmap](https://markmap.js.org) with a static site generator. Therefore I want to find an example where markmap is used from HTML. I.e., the HTML file should contain the Markdown statements to produce the desired mindmap. The idea is that the actual mindmap is produced during presentation time (=end user fetching the HTML), not during site generation time.

Unfortunately, the [documentation page](https://markmap.js.org/docs) of markmap does not provide such an example.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that works for your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517545/markmap-insert-the-mindmap-to-the-html

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for.

The example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517545/markmap-insert-the-mindmap-to-the-html does _not_ contain Markdown. It contains some kind of JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the author of [markmap](https://github.com/gera2ld/markmap), Gerald Liu. He prompty suggests to look at [markmap-autoloader](https://github.com/gera2ld/markmap/tree/master/packages/markmap-autoloader). Thanks Gerald!

The example is thus:

```
<html>
<body>

<style>
.markmap > svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>

<div class="markmap">
# markmap
## autoloader
## transformer
## view
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markmap-autoloader"></script>
</html>
```

Above code will produce below mindmap:
[markmap generated Mindmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZGyj.png)

This is what I now use in the static site generator [Simplified Saaze](https://eklausmeier.goip.de/blog/2021/10-31-simplified-saaze).